# Using sed to print last line to match pattern 'a' when a line matches pattern 'b'

Tags: text-processing, sed

I think that `sed` can be used to do this, but I'm not sure how. I'd like `sed` to run through a file looking for two patterns, 'a' and 'b'. When it encounters a line that matches 'b' I want to show the last line that matched 'a'. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this works:

```
sed -n '/a/{h};/b/{g;p}' file.txt
```

Comment: Or, with standard `sed`: `sed -n '/a/h;/b/{g;p;}'`